# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'usr'@'%' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql

I get above error message when try to use:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable INTO OUTFILE /tmp/test.txt CHARACTER SET latin1 FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

A simple select query work fine:

```
mysql> select count(*) from mytable;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|  1241551 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.21 sec)

mysql>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It signifies you don't have **FILE** privileges for this user. Please check.